# I need help on a Dovecot Virtual Mailboxes setup, should I be posting here on unix SE?

Tags: support

The question is in the title, I'm not trying to setup virtual users accounts but rather virtual mailboxes IN a user account.

This is to achieve a "Gmail" like feature of labels, but for some reason I get an error that I can't seem to find any answers on.

Thanks for guiding me. I'm not sure if Dovecot is on topic here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for it; questions about applications that run on Linux are fine. The [What topics can I ask about here?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of our help includes:

> - Applications packaged in *nix distributions

Comment: Thanks for your feedback :)